# Cloudflare Zero Trust in CI pipeline

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

Is it possible to use Cloudflare Zero Trust tunnel to access private machine (through SSH for example) from CI pipeline? I mean typically running it on local machine will fire SSO authorization. Ofc this method cannot be used in automated pipeline. Is there other way to authorize against Cloudflare Edge and in turn with external machine? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

use the `service token` for ci/cd.
https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/identity/service-tokens/

[allowci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfQjF.png)
[rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxaod.png)

You can check this blog https://blog.cloudflare.com/give-your-automated-services-credentials-with-access-service-tokens/

Comment: Thank you for your input. This will work for some scenarios, but what I need is to connect with kubectl (in CI) to private k8s cluster (with cloudflared). And I cannot add headers to kubectl as it is described in `service token` method

Comment: Btw, after adding headers to request JWT is returned. Should it be used later on or is it used authomatically?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).